# Function to calculate RSA crashes program after first print

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, rsa

Function stops running after first print

When I run the following and input p=7, q=11, it runs fine all the way through and prints both keys. However, if I chose slightly larger numbers suck as p=67, q=83 it prints the value of “e” (line 13) and then stops running and exits the program that this function is within entirely when it should print the keys and return to a home menu. Any ideas why this might be?

```
import random
import math

def create_key_set():
    p = int(input('Insert prime number for value of p: '))
    q = int(input('Insert new prime number for value of q: '))
    N = p * q
    y = (p-1) * (q-1)
    while True:
        cop = random.randint(2, y-1)
        gcd = math.gcd(cop, y)
        if gcd == 1:
            break
    e = cop
    print(e)
    pubkey = [e, N]
    while True:
        d = random.randint(1, 150)
        g, x = divmod((e*d), y)
        if x == 1:
            break
    print(d)
    privkey = [d, N]
    print('Public Key is: ', pubkey)
    print('Private Key is: ', privkey)
```

I’m don’t think it’s a computing issue because I tried it with cloud computing and it did the same thing. I definitely could be wrong though. Also it may be written terribly. This is the first time I’ve written python in a few years and I pretty much pieced it together from the internet. I’ve got no idea what’s wrong so any help on the issue and general tips in general would be appreciated.

Comment: *...then stops running and exits the program that this function is within entirely...* there is no way to exit that sequence except by raising an exception or completing normally. Perhaps your loop is running for a long time and you manually stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

The loop to find `d` (the second loop) is very likely to be an infinite loop. There's really no reason to use `randint` in that loop at all, and no reason to restrict `randint` to be between 1 and 150. Take out that entire loop and throw it away, and replace it with this one line: `d = pow(e, -1, y)`, so you're code looks something like

```py
def create_key_set():
    p = int(input('Insert prime number for value of p: '))
    q = int(input('Insert new prime number for value of q: '))
    N = p * q
    y = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    while True:
        cop = random.randint(2, y - 1)
        gcd = math.gcd(cop, y)
        if gcd == 1:
            break
    e = cop
    print(e)
    pubkey = [e, N]
    d = pow(e, -1, y)
    print(d)
    privkey = [d, N]
    print('Public Key is: ', pubkey)
    print('Private Key is: ', privkey)
```

Comment: I guess it was just running an infinite loop. However the formula you provided is an incorrect calculation of “d” I believe. The proper formula is e * d = 1 (mod y). How would I calculate “d” given “e” and “y” based on the above equation?

Comment: @HarrisonTaylor: The formula is correct, e*d = 1 mod y implies d = e^(-1) mod y. But just try it, go and try the code and add a `print((e * d) % y)` at the end. It will print out `1`.